# Access - prevent second form to open in different record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form from which I can Access 2 another forms. I can do that by clicking into selected record. What I want to do is prevent user to open second form in any different record that first form is allready opened. So far I have tried this (in Current event of 1st form - let me call It Main form):

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("MySecondForm").IsLoaded And CurrentProject.AllForms("MyThirdForm").IsLoaded Then
   If Forms![MySecondForm].Form![ID] = Forms![MyThirdForm].Form![ID] Then
        'do nothing

   Else

   ...

   MsgBox "Error. You cannot open both forms in different records !"

   End If

End If
```

Any ideas on which event I need to use code, and how to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, here is what I had to do:

```
  If Not CurrentProject.AllForms("MySecondForm").IsLoaded Then

      DoCmd.OpenForm "MyThirdForm", , , "ID=" & Forms![MainForm].Form![ID]

   ElseIf CurrentProject.AllForms("MySecondForm").IsLoaded Then

      DoCmd.OpenForm "MyThirdForm", , , "ID=" & Forms![MainForm].Form![ID]

      If Forms![MyThirdForm].Form![ID] = Forms![MySecondForm].Form![ID] Then

              'Do nothing

      Else

      MsgBox "Error. You cannot open both forms in different records !", vbCritical
              DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyThirdform"
              Exit Sub

      End If

   End If
```

If anybody has solution that would prevent opening form, please post. This solution opens form, checks record ID's and then closes form, which is not exactly perfect.